# ORBIT 100% height over 100% widht slider zurb foundation. 16:9 4:3

Tags: css, slider, height, zurb-foundation, orbit

I need some help with orbit slider.

I want to make it 100% width and 100% height , but....

I have a 1920x1080 slider images.

Images should always taking 100% height but width should be over 100% (if display propotion will change).

Just slider should crop width over browser window (`overflow: hidden;`)

```
.orbit {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: none;
}
.orbit-container{
    max-height: 100%;
}
.orbit-slide {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.orbit-image {
    max-width: none;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I will show you what I need in PS: [orbit 16:9 and 4:3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njcTo.jpg).

Comment: Would appreciate if you could share the required CSS as it helps to do a RCA and help you with the solution.

Comment: Actually css added to the post :) thanks for interesting ;)