# How to make front page slider in Sense/Net 6.5.4.9243 which cover full page dimension of web browser

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit, sensenet

I want to change default front page sensenet slider,which should cover full page of browser.I changed height of slides to 100% in file system and content explorer i also added  li{height:100%} and img{height:100%}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6wrz.png)
I also want to hide/remove by default slider name which show on images.

Answer (score 0):

There're two things to modify:

Open /Root/Global/renderers/Slider.ascx and change 'snmaxheight' in the slider config (line 117.)

```
snmaxheight: window.innerHeight
```

Add the following to the slider .css file (/Root/Global/styles/snSlider.css)

```
.orbit-container li .text {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: i also commented <h2><%= content["DisplayName"] %></h2> for hide slider title.

Comment: ok, I think it's not necessarry because it's in the .text container

Comment: It coming full screen in Google Chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox

Comment: why the same changes behaving  differently for different browsers?

Comment: The slider is an third-party javascript library in sensenet. For further information about this browser issues try to ask for or find help under orbit and zurb-foundation tags here on stackoverflow. For example here is another thread about slider height http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302922/orbit-100-height-over-100-widht-slider-zurb-foundation-169-43

Comment: I am keeping this issue on hold for sometime.